# Value of $f(-1)$ where $f(x) =x^{2/3}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

If f is a complex function defined by
$$f(x)= x^{\frac23}$$then how can we evaluate $f(-1)$?

My Approach:
$$(-1)^{2/3}=1^{1/3}=1$$
but the value of $f(-1)$ is given as approximately $-0.5 + 0.87i$, so how can I evaluate it?

Comment: It depends on how you *define* the complex function $f(z) = z^{2/3}$ (or which "branch" you choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using [Euler's famous identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), we can write: $$-1 = e^{i\pi} $$ Hence, $$f(-1)=(-1)^{2/3} = e^{2i \pi/3}$$ $$=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3}2i = - 0.5+0.866i$$ where we have used [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) in the last step.

Comment: But $-1 = e^{-i \pi}$ and $-1 = e^{3i \pi}$ hold as well, giving different results for $f(-1)$.

Comment: Yes, @MartinR I am aware. But, the OP can easily relate to the identity, right....

Comment: From your  $(e^{i\pi})^{2/3} = e^{2i \pi/3}$  the question author (who apparently is a beginner in complex analysis and not aware of "branches") might get impression that one can calculate $(z^a)^b = z^{ab}$ generally.

Answer (score 2):

If we limit ourselves to real calculations then $(-1)^{\frac 23}=1$ is well defined because we are in the case where the exponent $\in\mathcal Q_{odd}$ as I defined in this post:

[Exponential Equation with base -1, 0, and 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468708/exponential-equation-with-base-1-0-and-1/2468812#2468812)

$\mathcal x\in Q_{odd}\iff x=\frac pq$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q$ is odd.

In this case we can interchange the order of exponentiation, this is why it is well defined.
$(-1)^{\frac 23}=((-1)^2)^{\frac 13}=1^{\frac 13}=1=((-1)^{\frac 13})^2=(-1)^2=1$

---

Now if you go complex, there will always be three cubic roots, consisting of a real root multiplied by $1,j,j^2$ which are the cubic roots of unity.

Reminder: $\displaystyle j=e^{\large{i\frac{2\pi}3}}=-\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$

The operation is done like this: $(-1)^{\frac 23}=\exp(\frac 23\ln(-1))$

Where $\ln(-1)=i(\pi+2k\pi)$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$ is a multivalued function.

Thus $(-1)^{\frac 23}=\exp(i\frac{(4k+2)\pi}3)$ which takes only $3$ values $1,j,j^2$ as we have seen previously, when $k$ varies.

Answer (score 0):

A real number has exactly one cube root. But a (non-zero) complex number has *three* complex cube roots -  that other value for $f(-1)$ that you got from somewhere is one of the other cube roots of $1$.