# Graphing the function $(-2)^x$

Tags: graphing-functions

When I wanted to graph $y=(-2)^x$ many graphing calculator apps refused to plot it. TI-Nspire CAS plotted it as shown in the first picture. I think the plot is not correct as only the envelopes should be there with no values between the envelopes as shown in the second picture and the $(-2)^x$ should look like $2^x$ and $-(2^x)$ plotted on the same graph but of course with many discontinuities as explained in my analysis below. Am I right?

[$(-2)^x$ as graphed by the TI-Nspire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Buh.jpg)

[this is what I think it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YimfB.jpg)

Here’s my analysis of the function:

f(x)=(-2)^x

First: when x >=0

- if x is an integer, x>=0

(-2)^0=1

(-2)^1=-2

(-2)^2=4

(-2)^3=-8

(-2)^4=16

(-2)^x oscillates back and forth 
When x is an even integer (-2)^x is positive. 
When x is an odd integer (-2)^x is negative.

- when x is a rational number, x>0 
  let x=p/q    , p>0, q>0

(-2)^x=(-2)^(p/q)=((-2)^p)^(1/q)

if p is even and q is odd, (-2)^x is a positive real value 
Example: (-2)^(100/51)= 3.8927

if p is odd and q is odd, (-2)^x is a negative real value. 
Example: (-2)^(99/51)=-3.8402

if p is odd and q is even, (-2)^x is an imaginary value (not defined in the set of real numbers) 
Example: (-2)^(99/50)=i 3.9449

(Also in all the above cases, if you extend your analysis to include complex, we get q complex roots.)

In the domain of rational numbers, (-2)^x oscillate or is undefined (imaginary or complex)

- When x is irrational, x>0 
  (-2)^x has no real value. It has an infinite number of complex roots.

Second: when x<0 
(-2)^x=1/(-2)^|x| 
Use the same approach above to analyze the behavior of the function.

Comment: It's more like the second but it has infinitely many holes in it.

Comment: note that *what you think it should be* is not a function, because each $x$ gives two values of $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(-1)^x$ as defined in the real domain is only making sense for $x\in\mathbb Q_\text{odd}$

$=\{\frac pq\mid p\in\mathbb Z,q\in\mathbb N^*,\gcd(p,q)=1,\text{ and }q\text{ is odd }\}$

Have a look at this post for instance :
[Exponential Equation with base -1, 0, and 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468708/exponential-equation-with-base-1-0-and-1/2468812#2468812)

Thus the graph of $(-2)^x$ has holes on all points of ${\mathbb Q_\text{odd}}^\complement$.

More than a continuous graph with infinity of holes it is in reality more of a collection of isolated points in the plane. But I agree that thet are so close from each other that visually it looks like the curve you represented.
But if you could zoom up with infinite factor you would see a dashed line.

Comment: I added my analysis to the question and I understand the discontinuities presented in the function, but want to make sure the calculator graph is distorted due to maybe soft bugs. I emailed TI-Nspire CAS customer service to provide a clarification and try to improve their app.

Comment: @Ahmed The calculator is trying to trace it out, drawing a line from one plotted point to the next. This is not a good approach for discontinuous functions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $f(x)=(-2)^x$ is problematic for real numbers $x$. Think about what happens when $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $f(x)=(-2)^{\frac 1 2}=\sqrt{-2}$. Can you see why this is a problem to graph?

The graph of $f(x)=(-2)^x$ only makes sense for integer values of $x$. Also, as zwim pointed out in the comments, your second graph is not the graph of a function, as it is multivalued, i.e. one input of $x$ gives two outputs of $f(x)$.